# Broadcasting 37800bytes to 150 users using socket.io

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I am using `node.js`, `redis`, `socket.io`.

Application reads data from Redis, collects it in the array.

This array contains multiple user records. One user record is about `252 bytes` in size.

Hence, for 150 users this array will be of `37800 bytes`

When I broadcast this array in the room having 150 users connected I am facing lag in the application.

Above operations will happen after every 2 seconds.

I want to ask broadcasting this amount of data to socket is normal for socket.io applications, or is it heavy and I should think about shrinking the data size somehow ?

Comment: That's around 38kb, or 0.036 megabyte, which shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @adeneo : thanks for the reaply, i want to scale it to 500 users, so it will become 126000 bytes = 123Kb. And I read that, while broadcasting, it will require to write 123Kb for each socket[total 500 writes to socket]. Currently I can see the lag for 100+ users only.

Comment: @adeneo : also I tried removing this part from the application and then application worked fine without any lag.